# What is the expected number of walks with length  in Erdős–Rényi random graph?

Tags: random-graphs, random-matrices

Let $G(N, p)$ be a directed Erdős–Rényi random graph with edge probability $p$. Let $W_k$ denote the number of walks (potentially with repeated vertices, or repeated edges) of length $k$ beginning at a fixed vertex $i$ and terminating at a fixed vertex $j$. What is the expected number of walks, $\mathbb E [W_k]$?

From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4566722/what-is-the-expected-number-of-paths-with-length-k-in-erd%c5%91s-r%c3%a9nyi-random-graph), I know the expected number of paths is $(N!/(N-k)!)p^k.$

I think we can write $\mathbb E [W_k] = \sum_{n=1}^k p^k V_k$, where $V_k$ counts the number of walks with $k$ unique edges in the complete graph with $N$ vertices. Is there a nice formula for $V_k$?

An alternate way to phrase this problem is that I am looking for the expected value of $(A^k)_{ij}$, where $A$ is $N\times N$  matrix with Bernoulli random entries.